# Is there any penalty to wearing stolen items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a stolen silver ring. Does it affect people's reaction to me if I am wearing it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. But if you commit a crime and the guards catch you, they will keep all your stolen goods.

Comment: I found that if you got to the grey quarter in Windhelf, the shop there will take them off you

Answer (score 9):

No, they won't. But watch what you take; if you take highly valuable items or many moderately valuable items then you may find yourself being attacked by hired mercenaries with a contract to kill you. You will find the reason the mercenaries were hired and the name of who hired them in the letter. Also, getting caught doing **any** crime will result in the items you have stolen being taken back.

Comment: Getting _arrested_ will cause the items to be taken away. You can always fight your way out of being caught in the act of a crime.

Comment: The "I'd rather die then go to jail option doesn't mean fight, you can try running too

Comment: Mercenaries, they can ***try*** to kill me.